# PhpStorm column option

Tags: phpstorm, settings

I started learning Laravel, and also I got a licence for PhpStorm so I decided to use this software. I set it up without problems, but I'm having a problem with disabling this option which you can see in the picture.

I tried googling it, tried different things in PhpStorm settings, but I cant seem to turn off that 'column:' thingy.

[image: code in editor]

Answer (score 3):

In **Settings | Editor | General | Appearance**, try disabling **Show parameter name hints**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! I've been looking for this option for hours... once again, milion thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to the parameter name hints. You'll see those in other places too, not just for "column". You can disable them in the PHPStorm preferences at

> Editor->General->Appearance->Show parameter name hints

There's also an option there to configure when they will show up, if you want to leave them on in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is called [Parameter Hints](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/03/new-in-phpstorm-2017-1-parameter-hints/). Right-click on the hint (`column` in your case) and choose *Disable Hints*:

[image: Disable Hints]

You can also use this context menu to remove hints for this specific function name.